# What's the correct objective function for cosine similarity of two vectors to be 1 or 0?

Tags: machine-learning

The representation learning model produces vectors for objects. I want the cosine similarity of some vector pairs to be (close to) 1, some to be 0. What objective function should I use? MSE as training a regression model?

Comment: Hello CrazyMageQi,

You can actually use CosineSimilarity as the objective function, depending on the outcome of the solution that is expected. Could you elaborate a little more on the problem, so that we understand what is it that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @NischalHp CosineSimilarity is an objective function to maximize or minimize? That doesn't sound right.  I can give you an example. A deep learning model learn vector representations of words. So the input is the features extracted from words. The output of it is the word vectors. The training target is to make the value of cosine of vectors of pairs of synonyms to be 1 and others 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are a wide variety of loss metrics to compare two vectors (e.g., Triplet loss, Lifted Structure Loss, N-Pair loss, and Angular Loss).

Cosine distance (1-cosine similarity) can be used. Typically, a loss metrics needs to be minimized so distances metrics should be used.